# Получить последний символ TextView

Tags: android, java

Есть `TextView`. В нем n-ное количество строк.
Возможно ли получить последний символ 3-ей строки? А если быть точнее - позицию этого символа.

Comment: Swing? AWT? JavaFX? Android?

Comment: да, забыл указать. xD. android

Answer (score 3):

Количество строк TextView зависит от Layout'а, так что надо примерно так:

```
TextView tv;
int lines=tv.getLineCount(); //работает только после onLayout()/onMeasure()
float height=tv.getLineHeight();
if(lines < 3)
 //
else {
   Rect rect;
   tv.getLineBounds(2, rect); //координаты top/left, right/bottom строки
   //позиция последнего символа в 3-й строке
   int ch=tv.getOffsetForPosition(rect.right-tv.getMinWidth(), rect.bottom-     height/2); //если текст слева-направо
}
```

Comment: опять же я не уточнил. текст у меня не вмещается в одну строку и переносится. я не вручную указываю "\n" поэтому getLineHeight(); всегда равен 0

Comment: `getLineHeight()` не может быть равен "0". Вы скорее всего его вызываете в `onCreate()` где он действительно равен "0" - внимательнее читайте мои комментарии. И второе я нигде не говорил про перевод каретки!

Comment: простите за невнимательность! я его вызываю из адаптера (где идет добавление текста в текствью). что я не так делаю? (адаптер - мой класс который расширяет baseAdapter)

Answer (score 1):

Android:

```
String[] lines = textView1.getText().toString().split( "\n" /* или "\r\n" */ );
if( lines.length > 2 ) {
    String line = lines[2];
    return line[line.length - 1];
} else {
    // а что, если строк меньше трёх?
}
```

Comment: вот это реально круто. спасибо! попробую.

Comment: @atwice Ответ неверен, поскольку в многострочном `TextView` количество строк зависит от `Layout`'а внутри которого находится `TextView` - так что здесь надо похитрее :)

Comment: не работает! я не уточнил то, что перенос строки формирую я не сам. если текст не вмещается - то строка переносится. у всех текствьювов (это все я делаю в листвью) значение lines.length() = 1